# In Swift Charts, how can I control whether the LineMark extends beyond the chart area boundary?

Tags: swiftui, charts

I am building a chart for an iOS app using the Charts library. I want to re-create the effect seen in the "sun movement example" below, where my line goes up to the edge of the plot area but does not extend outside of the chart edge. However, the line of my chart is displaying outside of the chart's left, bottom, and right edges.

[sun movement example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9UMI.png)

[current SwiftUI chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAw5r.png)

Is there a property somewhere on the Chart or perhaps the LineMark that I need to set in order to contain the line so that it only extends up to the edge of the plot area?

Here's what I'm currently running:

```
                Chart(data, id: \.DateTime) {
                dataPoint in
                LineMark(x: .value("DateTime", dataPoint.DateTime),
                         y: .value("Feet", dataPoint.HeightFeet))
                            .interpolationMethod(.cardinal)
            }
            .padding()
            .chartYScale(domain: [0, 8])                
            .chartXScale(domain: [SelectedDate - 21600, SelectedDate + 86400])
            .chartPlotStyle { chartContent in
                        chartContent
                            .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.2))

                        }
```

I've searched far and wide, but most examples of the Charts library are built off of small data sets, where all of the data is displayed on the chart. My scenario is a bit different in that the data set also contains data beyond the range that I intend to display.

I have tried applying different properties such as .chartXScale, .chartXAxis, .chartPlotStyle, etc. So far no luck getting the line to stop at the edge of the chart!

I am brand new to iOS development and to Stack Overflow. Please let me know if I can provide additional context to help explain this question!